# Python: why can isinstance return False, when it should return True?

Tags: python, isinstance

I'm currently in pdb trace to figure this out

```
ipdb> isinstance(var, Type)
False
ipdb> type(var)
<class 'module.Type'>
ipdb> Type
<class 'module.Type'>
```

Why can this happen?

P. S. `isinstance(var, type(var))` returns `True` as expected

Comment: There could be multiple types known as `Type` (say at different points in time). Could you produce a complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: is there any `import`/`reload` magic in your code?

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk, I don't think so. Can you provide examples of such magic?

Comment: @Shark http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk no, there is definitely no reload statement in my source code.

Comment: I just hit the same problem today.  It was absolute import vs relative import.   Try `print repr(var.__class__), repr(Type)`.  I resolved the problem by changing the relative import to absolute import.  I will create a code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. I can only guess, but if you do in `module`

   ```
   class Type(object): pass
   var = Type()
   class Type(object): pass
   ```

   then both types look like `<class 'module.Type'>`, but are nevertheless different.

   You could check that with

   ```
   print(id(Type), id(var.__class__))
   ```

   or with

   ```
   print(Type is var.__class__)
   ```

   Note that these comparisons work for both old-, and new-style classes.
   For new-style classes, they are equivalent to `print(Type is type(var))`.
   But this is not the case for old-style classes.
2. Another quite common trap is that you call this module with

   ```
   python -m module
   ```

   or

   ```
   python module.py
   ```

   making it known as `__main__` module. If it is imported somewhere else under its true name, it is known under that name as well with a different name space.
3. Another guess could be that you are working with [ABCs](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#overloading-isinstance-and-issubclass) or otherwise let the class have a `__instancecheck__()` method.

Comment: I have defined only one Type across all of my source files.
And I'm not fiddling with hidden methods. Only `__str__`, `__iter__`, `__len__`. So this is not the case. Also, this class is subclass of `object`.

Comment: BTW, I'm currently in pdb session. What should I check to determine cause?

Comment: You might consider taking a look at `id(type(var))`, `type(var) is Type`, etc.

Comment: for old-style classes, compare `Type is var.__class__`, because `Type is type(var)` can fail. This remains relevant, because of `distutils` classes that are monkey-patched by `setuptools`.

Comment: #2 Solved it for me. Changed `from module.sub_module.thing import SpecificThing` to `import module.sub_module.thing as thing` and then referenced `thing.SpecificThing` in the code and the problem was fixed. This was fixed even though I was using IPython autoreload as described below.

Answer (score 16):

Users of the "autoreload" setting in iPython will probably run into this. When a class is reloaded, it will become a new class with the exact same name. Instances of the old class will not have their type updated:

```
# After reloading the Role class

[ins] In [19]: y = Role()

[ins] In [20]: isinstance(x, Role)
Out[20]: False

[nav] In [21]: isinstance(y, Role)
Out[21]: True

[ins] In [22]: type(x)
Out[22]: myproject.auth.Role

[ins] In [23]: type(y)
Out[23]: myproject.auth.Role
```

Comment: Any option aside `imp.reload(module)` and re-instantiating `x`? I could open a question

Comment: I had this when I used importlib.reload in the wrong order: library 1 called library 2, but I did importlib.reload for library 1 first before library 2, so every isinstance failed.

Comment: @Hubro you saved my life. I just ran into this problem and it took me over an hour to find your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem as well, for me to problem laid in my imports. I imported `Type` once from `parent.child.Type` and once from `child.Type`. I assume that when using the full path the module is imported from the installed pip package, whereas using the relative path it is imported as a new module on the fly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).